# нужно сделать мигание JButton

Tags: java

надо сделать анимацию из кнопок

1.как реализовать периодическую смену цвета кнопки

2.пока работает цикл паралельно слушать кнопку "Stop" и при нажатии ставить цикл на паузу

код

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Button;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class testV extends JFrame{
JPanel windowContent= new JPanel();
Panel centerPanel=new Panel();
JButton squares[][];
Button newGameButton;
Label scored;
int turn=0;String trn=Integer.toString(turn);
Color clearCell=new Color(212, 208, 200);

public testV()  {
    windowContent.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    newGameButton=new Button("Stop");
    newGameButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            if(newGameButton.getLabel()=="Stop") {
               //здесь ставить цикл на паузу
                newGameButton.setLabel("Play");
            }
            else if(newGameButton.getLabel()=="Play") {
            //здесь снимать с паузы
                newGameButton.setLabel("Stop");
            }
        }
    });
    Panel topPanel=new Panel(new BorderLayout());
    topPanel.add(newGameButton,"South");
    windowContent.add(topPanel,"South");
    scored=new Label(trn);
    topPanel.add(scored,"North");

    centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(5,5));
    windowContent.add(centerPanel,"Center");
    squares=new JButton[5][5];

    for(int i=0;i<squares.length;i++){
         for (int j = 0; j < squares[i].length; j++){
             squares[i][j]=new JButton();
             squares[i][j].setBorderPainted(false);
             squares[i][j].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
             centerPanel.add(squares[i][j]);
        }
     }

    if(turn<10)
     M1();

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
     setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 500));
     setContentPane(windowContent);
     pack();     
     setVisible(true);
}//public Logo() 

void M1() {//тут мы должны последовательно менять цвет
    slp();
    st();
    squares[2][2].setBackground(clearCell);
    slp();
    st();
    squares[2][2].setBackground(Color.BLACK);
}

void slp() {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(500);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {e.printStackTrace();
        Thread.currentThread().interrupt();}
}

void st(){
    turn=turn+1;
    trn=Integer.toString(turn);
    scored.setText(trn);
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
                new testV();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

что же вы молчали, нужно всего лишь на ночь...
запустить новый поток

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {//новый поток
        public void run() {
                for (int i = 0; i < 6; i++) {
                    M1(); 
                }
        }
        }).start();
```